# How do I store the input on a numeric up down value in windows forms in a variable and use that variable as a labels text?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm working on a windows forms assignment and am not good at C#. I have a numeric up-down control that represents a tip and the professor wants me to add whatever the user inputs on that to display it into a label's text and then add it to the total.

This is the code I have now:
`int count = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value); textBoxTip.Text = count.ToString();`

Do I need an event handler? I don't understand the event handlers yet.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try control label and on change event of numericupdown

Comment: @LeandroBardelli I am sorry but I am very new to C sharp what would that look like in code?

Comment: Dont over engineer it: `mycontrol.Text = numericUpDown1.Value.ToString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an assignment so, don't expect someone on SO to do it for you, but never the less here are some things that maybe can guide you towards a solution.

You probably want your code to react to changes on your `numericUpDown1`. There are different events that handle changes on that control. The one you are probably looking for might be `NumericUpDown.ValueChanged` ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0 )

You said you don't understand event handlers yet. An event handler is a method that is to be registered with a (usually) specific type of event in order to have some code react to the specified event happening. For example if you have a button and click it, you expect "something" to happen. This "something" is code that is located in such an event handler, in this case a handler designed for the `onClick` event of a button.

In order to register such a method with an event you can use `someControl.someEvent += myEventHandler;` and in case you need to un-register the event you can use `someControl.someEvent -= myEventHandler;`. If you work with the VisualStudio Forms designer, you will probably have noticed the call to `InitializeComponent()` in your Forms constructor. if you look at the source for that method, you will find the code generated by the Forms designer. If you have a button on your form and hooked up the click event via the Forms designer (double click on the button, or via the properties panel), you will have code there that registers the event. Do not edit that code unless you know what you are doing. Your event registration should be fine if you place it after the `InitializeComponent()` call in the constructor. If you don't work with the Forms designer and write the code for populating your Form with controls yourself, the event registration obviously goes after the instance creation of the control you want to react on. (Or wherever else is suitable for your needs, but since you are only starting with event handlers... place the registration there for now)

`myEventHandler` in this case is the event handler method and could look something like this:

```
public void myEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e){
   //your code here
   //for example pull the value from your input control
   //and write it to your label
}
```